# How do I install the Guidance Package templates for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

I have GAT 2010, GAX 2010 and SCSF 2010 extensions installed for VS2010 Ultimate. I had the Guidance Package templates for creating modules used CAB projects. Today I found out that they are now missing and I can't seem to get them back. I've tried running devenv /installvstemplates as suggested for other missing templates, but that didn't work. I've also reinstalled all three extension packages and that still didn't fix it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guidance Package somehow became disassociated with my project. By opening the Guidance Navigator from menu under View > Other Windows > Guidance Navigator, I was able to select the Smart Client Software Factory 2010 package and re-associate it with the project. After I did that, the templates reappeared in the new project wizard.